# Single array element becomes object with Zend_Soap_Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I'm using Zend_Soap_Client and encountering this issue:

```
<parent>
    <child><name>abc</name></child>
    <child><name>def</name></child>
</parent>
```

If there's more than one child element then Zend return array and I can access like

`$result->parent->child[0]->name`

but if there's only one child node it returns object like:

`$result->parent->child->name`

Can you please let me know what's wrong with my approach or how can I overcome it?

My sample code:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('url', array('wsdl'=>'url));
$result = $client->getResult();
```

I'm using zend 1.9. The same issue happens with PHP's native SoapClient

Thanks!

Comment: if(is_object($result->parent->child))....maybe with that you can do something and cast the result into an array

Comment: is_array() should be used since is_object() will be true in both case. Array is also an object. Right now I'm using this but since there are several such elements I don't this is the best way to go. Thanks!

Comment: You have two cases: 1) $result->parent->child is an array, 2) is an object...if if not an array, then use an aux var and cast $result->parent->child to an array...i think it's a good aproach

Comment: I tried, but no success. I used (array) to cast and $result->parent->child = array($result->parent-data->child) but no success. It throws invalid argument in foreach loop. Can you please right code if Im doing it wrong?

Comment: Show me the structure of your foreach loop to provide you the right code ;)

Comment: <?php if (is_array($this->result->availableServices->availableService->serviceDetails->serviceDetail)): ?>
                            <?php foreach ($this->result->availableServices->availableService->serviceDetails->serviceDetail as $serviceItem): ?>
                                 <br><a href="#">&bull; <?= $serviceItem ?></a><br>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <br><a href="#">&bull; <?= $this->result->availableServices->availableService->serviceDetails->serviceDetail ?></a><br>
<?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally I do not see the need to use `Zend_Soap_Client` instead of `SoapClient` because the Zend version does not add anything beneficial, but on the other hand the solution applies to both:

There is an options array parameter in the original `SoapClient` that accepts plenty of things, and especially this below ([ref](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)):

> The **features** option is a bitmask of SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,...

With this option, all array structures in the soap response are not reduced to one single element if they contain only one, but left as is. You are always accessing an array then, which is easier than switching depending on the content.

Example:

```
$s = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
```

Comment: Thanks! Even with SoapClient I'm getting same result but SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS seems a hope.. Let me give it a try...